# Is it possible to compile .NET 1.1 in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have an ASP.NET 1.1 website and was recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2008. It looks like after compiling my projects into .dll's, that they are not working and from what I've gathered, it seems that it's due to VS2k8 not being able to target .NET 1.1. I still have Visual Studio 2003 installed, so I can compile my projects with that, but I'm wondering if there is any way to compile these in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: i think you can only target 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 frameworks in VS 2008

Comment: VS2008 can do this because it targets the CLR 2.0, but this CLR supports three different versions of the .NET Framework (2.0, 3.0, 3.5). Swapping between those is a simple matter of selectively limiting which standard assemblies you are allowed to reference. Supporting .NET 1.1 would involve being able to swap between different CLRs, which is a different matter entirely.

Comment: @Christian - Thanks, gives me a better understanding of what's happening. I'll do some reading after I get my solution in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the minimum you can target is .NET 2.0. Why not just upgrade the project to .NET 2.0 or better yet 3.5?

The [change in ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163901.aspx) alone (never mind the other benefits) is one reason to do it.

Answer (score 2):

you can't [as pet Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/20/vs-2008-multi-targeting-support.aspx)

but [this article](http://devlicio.us/blogs/ziemowit_skowronski/archive/2008/08/22/working-with-net-1-1-in-visual-studio-2008-and-team-server.aspx) gives you a work-around

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of thing that [MSBee](http://www.codeplex.com/MSBee) was created to address (albeit for Visual Studio 2005).  The same can be applied to Visual Studio 2008.  See this article for details on how to set it up as well as limitations that you might consider:

http://devlicio.us/blogs/ziemowit_skowronski/archive/2008/08/22/working-with-net-1-1-in-visual-studio-2008-and-team-server.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No you can only target .NET 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 (have a look at the properties of your project).

This will also be true for VS 2010 (of course adding .NET 4.0 to the list), as [described by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/27/multi-targeting-support-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx).

Comment: I have, and since I saw no 1.1 option, I asked SO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, but its a hack. There is a blog article here on how to do it with a beta edition of VS2005 here  - http://blogs.msdn.com/jomo_fisher/archive/2005/04/22/410903.aspx You might be able to adapt this to work with VS2008.

My recommendation however would be to either use VS2003 or .Net 2.0.

Comment: There's another one here- http://tech.einaregilsson.com/2008/01/15/developing-aspnet-1-1-in-visual-studio-2008/. Can't see why anyone would try this though versus the upgrade route!

Comment: The need to develop for the .Net 1.1 framework, although if that was the case I'd stick with VS2003

Answer (score 0):

There's the line:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

in the csproj file.

I wouldn't recommend it, but you could try setting the value to v1.1. However, I suspect it would cause more problems than it would solve.

I would go with RichardOD's suggestion and either bite the bullet and upgrade or find a version of Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a supported operation in Visual Studio 2008.  It only supports compiling to the 2.0 and 3.5 framework.